# view nlog's output as a web page with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, nlog

In an ASP.NET application, is there a way to get the nlog output to go in a buffer in memory?

I'd like to make a circular buffer that would display the log's content on a web page.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Im planning to write my own NLogViewer Webinterface. Maybe you want to contribute? https://github.com/dojo90/NLogViewer

Comment: yes, I used the memory target; I had forgotten about this question and I just marked Julian's answer as the correct one. I put the code I used here: https://pastebin.com/3urQjc75 so you can have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about writing to the [memory target](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Memory-target)?

Then you could read them as follow:

```
var target = LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName<MemoryTarget>("target1");
var logs = target.Logs;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify custom targets with NLog: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Targets

It does not look like one exists that does exactly what you need, but you can write your own!

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Extending-NLog

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you read tail n-lines from the actual log file and display it? Or send to a database and display the table? Seems that this will added more overhead and memory constants to the ASP.Net site.

Comment: reading back from the log file, or writing and reading back from a database is certainly going to cost a lot more cpu time than having a circular buffer in ram